# Why does StackOverflow "promote" Microsoft products like Win8?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, policy, contest

**Before you read: Please note that I'm not criticizing SE, which has done quiet good things to make the web a better place. I'm just trying to understand the SE policy.**

I've seen many events by SE, like the recent [Apptivate.MS competition](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/windows-devs-on-stack-overflow-when-did-this-happen/), that are in a way or in other "promoting" Microsoft or one of its products.

While I know that there might be some commercial reasons behind that, like a "deal" between SE and Microsoft - and that is definitely fine in principle. I just wonder: StackExchange is all about making the world a better place (well, the web is part of the world, after all!).

Microsoft is, obviously, a profit (no problem with that) closed source company that has its activities in fighting open source and free software (despite the few open source projects it participates), and has bad effects and activities in matters of web, user privacy, openness.. etc.

If that is the case, what is the philosophy behinds SE's acceptance to deal with Microsoft? As far as I can understand: Promoting "badly" closed source software/companies doesn't really make the web a better place.

Comment: Wait until you find out some of the top contributors work at Microsoft.

Comment: looks like we should leave this on so ... its there own  policy

Comment: @Rapptz: I already know that, but that has no relation with the subject in my opinion.

Comment: I think you dislike Microsoft.

Comment: Possibly has something to do with them using ASP.NET MVC to build SE/SO or the fact that MS [approaches them](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/apptivate-ms-a-windows-8-app-development-contest/) to host / advertise for them... but these are just guesses.

Comment: people now are downvoting before reading the question .. downvote first , read it later!

Comment: @M.H They're downvoting because of the whole open/closed source religious debate, and the assumptions made about that debate in the question.

Comment: I agree. The question is basically "WAAAAH OPEN SOURCE, MICROSOFT ISN'T OPEN!!1".

Comment: @DeadMG: It's not like that, but rather: Open Source makes the web a better place, Microsoft doesn't, SE want's the web to be a better place (as Jeff and Joel always said), wasn't that obvious?

Comment: Nobody actually cares about ~the web~, everyone wants money though

Comment: @Tamer: Yeah, we know.  We just don't agree, either with your premise or your conclusions.

Comment: Also, I liked the other "Microsoft sucks" post more

Comment: "Please note that I'm not criticizing SE" - really? Because that's what the question *really* sounds like...

Answer (score 15):

Stack Exchange doesn't have an opinion about the whole open/closed source debate, nor should they.

I'm not privy to Stack Exchange's internal financial dealings, but I suspect they do make a few dollars on Apptivate.MS.  They are, after all, a for-profit company just like Microsoft.

Your open-source friends are certainly welcome to engage SE under a similar agreement, to create something like`Opensource.it`

Answer (score 8):

Windows 8 is a brand new platform, and It will cause a large number of fresh programming questions to arise.

It's not about promoting any company, but It's about supporting important programming events.  A lot of people are going to need help, and SO wants to encourage people to answer those new fresh questions.

The more that people work in Win-8 Apps, the more fit they are to answer Win-8 questions.